# How to open a .pkl file

Tags: python, pickle

Although there's a lot of subjects related to my question already, the answers are usually no understandable for me, as I am just a beginner in the "writting scripts in Python" field.

Here is my situation :

There's a machine learning software that writes models in a `.pkl` format at the end of its learning phase. I would like to make those `model.pkl` files openable by an operator to check what there is inside the model. Thus I began to write a script that would use the `pickle.load` method and write the data contained in my `model.pkl` into a `.txt` file. Here's what I wrote to begin with:

```
import pickle 
import os 

model_path=input("Model Path = ")
with open(model_path, "rb") as model :
    load = pickle.load(model, encoding='utf-8')
    new_model_path = model_path.split('.pkl')[0] +'.txt'
    print("creating new file at : ", new_model_path)
    model_readable = open(new_model_path, 'rt')
    model_readable.write(load)
    print("writing model as readable : ", load)
model_readable.close()
model.close()
```

If I try to run it here's the output :

```
python3.7 unpickler.py    
Model Path = /home/ouriacc/Desktop/workspace/SESAM/Base_de_tests/Anomalie_1/Models/OCSVM/EyeSat/CI_HEATER_CAMERA_VOLTAGE.pkl
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "unpickler.py", line 7, in <module>
        load = pickle.load(model, encoding='utf-8')
    _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '_'.
```

I couldn't find any explanation about this error that didn't imply an incomplete or corrupted download, which can't be my case here as the model.pkl files are not modified once they've been created by the AI software.

Could someone help me to solve the error or even indicate me an other methode to achieve my goal ? All I need is a script that gives access for a user to what the .pkl file contains.

Thank you very much !

Comment: Is the version of `pickle` that is being used to generate the `.pkl` file the same version that you have? `import pickle print(pickle.__version__)`

Comment: Yes I generated the files on my computer using the same python librairies (python 3.7 librairies).

Comment: Are you using `scikit-learn` to create your model(s)?

Comment: Yes I am indeed ! does it have an incidence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out why @wundermahn asked about `scikit-learn`. It seems my `model.pkl` files were generated by `joblib` and not exactly `pickle` library. This is why it wouldn't work apparently. It changed my code by replacing `pickle.load()` by `joblid.load()` and it works better !

Thank you !